# using keras to predict a binomial function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm just exploring keras under python.

I've created a training array of constants where y=x*2+1
(very simple binomial function)

When i try to predict on 24 and 40 i get

```
array([[2429427.8],
       [2429427.8]], dtype=float32)
```

i would expect to get

```
array([[49],
           [81]], dtype=float32)
```

or close.

What is going on here?

## Code

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Activation
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]])
y = np.array([3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=200, input_dim=1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=45))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='sgd')

model.fit(X, y, epochs=40, batch_size=50, verbose=1)

test=np.array([[24],[40]])
model.predict(test)
```

My ultimate goal for this little script is to switch to the X array having two features

ie. `([1,3],[3,7],[5,11],[6,1])`
and y labels ie. `([1],[1],[1],[0])`

so that i can use the model to predict when a candidate (ie. [400,14]) doesn't fit the binomial function.

Thanks in advance!

Happy Machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's talk about the regression output error in your question. You need to normalize the input data. Otherwise your model won't learn anything.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Activation
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]])
y = np.array([3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21])
# normalize the input data
X_mean = X.mean()
X_std = X.std()
X = (X-X_mean)/X_std

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=200, input_dim=1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=45))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='sgd')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=40, batch_size=50, verbose=1)

test=np.array([[24],[40]])
# normalize the input data
test = (test-X_mean)/X_std
result = model.predict(test)
print(result)

# print
Using TensorFlow backend.
Epoch 1/40
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 96ms/step - loss: 176.4364
...
...
[[50.623974]
 [84.23475 ]]
```

Comment: Thanks, scaling is clearly an issue with that code. That definitely takes things in the right direction. But if you add four or five more values to the array the loss starts to hit nan

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using pandas as the following:

```
import pandas as pd
X = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[3,7],[5,11],[6,1]])
y = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,0])
```

You also need to set the input_dim to 2 as you are using 2 features of each example. The final code is:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Activation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X=pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[3,7],[5,11],[6,1]])
y=pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,0])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=200, input_dim=2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=45))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='sgd')

model.fit(X, y, epochs=40, batch_size=50, verbose=1)

test=np.array([[24,40]])
print model.predict(test)
```

Meanwhile, I think that you need more examples and to play a bit with number of nodes/hidden layers of your neural network.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your help! I tried to run your code and the prediction was [[3.1780818]] and when i set the numbers to the correct relationship using ([[24,49]]) i then get [[4.487226]]. Shouldn't i be getting between 0 and 1? those results dont seem to relate atall stil?

Comment: As I told you in the response, you need to add more example and fine tune the neural network parameters. The goal is to have a loss the most closer possible to 0. I tried with 1000 epoch, I got 1.00525641. Hope this helps you.

Comment: even on 1000 epochs its giving me strange numbers (just under 4 for a what should be labelled as a 1). I'm assuming it needs to finish on a layer with sigmoid activation to end up as a binary score? either way though its impossible to see whether your solution as an improovement at the moment

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution, I added a sig in the last layer, I got 1 as result. Hope that will help you.